# What is RDBMS and database engine?

Tags: database, rdbms

It's kinda a noob question but what is the difference between Relational Database Management System and database engine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original idea of an RDBMS differs from what is called an RDBMS these days. SQL DBMSs are commonly called RDBMSs, but it's more correct to say they can be used mostly relationally, if one has the knowledge and discipline. It's also possible to use them in the style of a network data model or even inconsistently, which seems like the more common attitude in the field.

The essence of the relational model is not about tables, but about first-order logic. Tables are simply a general-purpose data structure which can be used to represent relations. For example, a graph can be viewed in a relational way - as a set of ordered pairs - and can be represented as a table (with some rules to ensure the table is interpreted or manipulated correctly). By describing all data using domains, relations, dependencies and constraints, we can develop declarative consistency guarantees and allow any reasonable question to be answered correctly from the data.

A database engine is software that handles the data structure and physical storage and management of data. Different storage engines have different features and performance characteristics, so a single DBMS could use multiple engines. Ideally, they should not affect the logical view of data presented to users of the DBMS.

How easily you can migrate to another DBMS / engine depends on how much they differ. Unfortunately, every DBMS implements somewhat different subsets of the SQL standard, and different engines support different features. Trying to stick to the lowest common denominator tends to produce inefficient solutions. Object-relational mappers reintroduce the network data model and its associated problems which the relational model was meant to address. Other data access middleware generally don't provide a complete or effective data sublanguage.

Whatever approach you choose, changing it is going to be difficult. At least there's some degree of overlap between SQL implementations, and queries are shorter and more declarative than the equivalent imperative code, so I tend to stick to simple queries and result sets rather than using data access libraries or mappers.

Comment: Thanks for the information sir, this just came out of my mind when I purchased an item with free sdk where in it is said that its database engine will only last for 30 days. So I just wander if I could use other types of database engine.

Answer (score 3):

A relational database management system (RDBMS) is a database management system (DBMS) that is based on the relational model where in you can create many tables and have relations between them. While  database engine is the underlying software component that a database management system (DBMS) uses to perform the operations from a database

Comment: The relational model has nothing to do with "relations between [tables]". Rather, tables are used to represent relations, which enables ternary and higher relationships to be supported. Conflating FK constraints with relationships takes us back to the network data model.